# Trailing newline character

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a text file with 32 binary numbers, each one is in separate line and each number is 8 characters long. I want to store them in the `mem` array as strings.

Right now, this code looks like this:

```
    char mem[32][9];
    char line[9];

    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file \"%s\"!", filename);
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file_pointer)) {
            memcpy(mem[i], line, 8);
            mem[i][8] = '\0';
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file_pointer);
```

Unfortunately I still get newline characters in `line`, so my array is not displaying properly.

This is my console when I am printing the array:

```
00      00110100
01

02      01111100
03

04      10011100
05

06      10010101
etc...
```

My code for printing the array:

```
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if (i >= 10) {
        printf("%d", i);
    } else {
        printf("%c%d", '0', i);
    }
    printf("\t%s\n", mem[i]);
}
```

I tried also using:

```
strtok(line, "\n");

line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: `memcpy(mem[i],line,8);` what do expect to see if `line` has less than 8 characters?

Comment: Change `line[9]` to `line[100]`. And change `memcpy` to `strncpy`.

Comment: `char line[9];` --> `char line[10];` : 8 + `\n` + `\0`

Comment: Also, if you want to print two-digit numbers with leading zeros, use `printf("%02d", i)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There is no need to declare line either like char[100] or char[10]. The declaration of line is correct.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow E.g input `00110100`+enter ==> fgets ==> `00110100\0` (`\n` remain stdin)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `fgets` stops when it fills the buffer OR when it reaches the newline. If the buffer isn't big enough, the newline won't be read until the next call to `fgets`. So the buffer should always be much bigger than it needs to be, so that you never read a partial line.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, I have updated my answer I doubted whether the new line character will be in the buffer or will be extracted.:).

Comment: Note that although `char line[10];` is the minimum safe length, it assumes a perfectly valid file (or, at least, no lines longer than 8 characters plus newline plus null byte).  It would be sensible to allow for overlong lines too.  Use `char line[4096];` or something similarly huge.  You can use that to detect and reject overlong lines; you could use it to detect and reject short lines too — but that would be doable with shorter lengths.  You could consider checking that the characters are all digits, etc.  It depends in part on how stringent you want to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes about your code:

- You must make `line` longer so `fgets()` can read the `'\n'` into `line`.  Currently it breaks each line into an 8 byte chunk and an empty line with the newline character.
- You should prevent the `while` loop from reading beyond the end of the array.

Here is an improved version

```
    char mem[32][9] = { 0 };
    char line[80];

    FILE *file_pointer = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file \"%s\"!\n", filename);
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 32 && fgets(line, sizeof line, file_pointer)) {
            strncat(mem[i], line, 8);
            i++;
        }
        if (i < 32) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Missing values in file \"%s\": found %d lines\n",
                    filename, i);
        }
        fclose(file_pointer);
    }
```

You could also simplify the printing code this way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%02d\t%s\n", i, mem[i]);
    }
```

Note that if you are certain about the file format, you can simplify the reading code this way:

```
    char mem[32][9];
    char line[80];

    FILE *file_pointer = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file \"%s\"!\n", filename);
    } else {
        if (fread(mem, 9, 32, fp) != 32) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Missing bytes in file %s\n", filename);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                mem[i][8] = '\0';
            }
        }
        fclose(file_pointer);
    }
```

You might also want to verify that the strings in `mem[]` contain exactly 8 hexadecimal digits with a simple loop and using the `isxdigit()` function from `<ctype.h>`:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < 8; i++) {
                    if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)mem[i][j])
                        break;
                }
                if (j != 8 || mem[i][8] != \n') {
                    fprintf("invalid data on line %d\n", i + 1);
                }
                mem[i][8] = '\0';
            }
```

Comment: Would it be worth showing that error messages should be printed to standard error?  Also, the `fclose()` should be inside the `else` block; `fclose()` is allowed to (and usually does) crash when passed a null pointer.